# Text and text color from an int value

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have four integer values: 1, 2, 3 and 4.
Instead of printing the int values, I have to transform to a corresponding text.

```
1 -> my text 1
2 -> another text
3 -> yet another one
4 -> text 4
```

Also I have to change the color:

```
1 -> gray
2 -> black
3 -> blue
4 -> green
```

So I did this:

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"",@"my text 1",@"another text", @"yet another one", @"text 4", nil];
myTextLabel.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:myInt];
```

But how to get the color code? Normally I do this:

```
myTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

But how can I do this with my list? And also, what is the best way to to the transformation of an integer value to a text and a text color code? Perhaps there is a better way?

Thank you in advance & Best Refards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same way :

```
NSArray *myColorArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [UIColor whiteColor], [UIColor greyColor], [UIColor blueColor], [UIColor greenColor], nil];
myTextLabel.textColor = [myColorArray objectAtIndex:myInt];
```

For the index 0, you can't use nil, so put a color that you know you won't use.

Comment: Okay, my error was, that I defined the first value `nil`. But where should I integrate these lines? I think the best place would be the domain object where the integer value is a class variable. Shoul I set these values also as class properties?

Comment: This is really depending on where you are using this array... declare the array as the class attribute, and create it in the class constructor. You can also declare it static if you need to access it from everywhere without creating an object or accessing a singleton.

Answer (score 2):

Are these hard-coded at compile-time? If so, you might find that this works better:

```
static struct { NSString *text; UIColor *color; } map[] = {
    { @"my text 1"      , [UIColor grayColor ] },
    { @"another text"   , [UIColor blackColor] },
    { @"yet another one", [UIColor blueColor ] },
    { @"text 4"         , [UIColor greenColor] },
};
```

Comment: And how can I access them? Because the int value 0 does not exist. It is a value of the database.

Comment: Subtract one from the integer.

Comment: Okay, perfect, I did this. But last question: where should I put the struct into? In my ViewController it works, but into the domain object I get the error `Initializer element is not a compile-tme constant` if I place it after my @synthesize's. I think it is related to my domain object, so I should place it there and in the ViewController I should access the values and bind it to the UI.

Comment: Hehe, I often forget that not everyone uses C++. This trick works best when used locally within a function. If you need to use it from more than one function, you can define the struct as a named struct somewhere "public", and define the array as a static local in a function who's sole purpose in life is to accept an int and return a pointer to the corresponding struct. Alternatively, you could give your source file a .mm extension and the error will magically disappear (though the compiler might start to complain about all kinds of things elsewhere in your code).

Comment: Oh sorry, I do not understand all, because I have no C++ experience. I think struct is a good way in this case. It is related to a domain object in which I get the integer value. So the struct should be placed there... but where exactly?

Comment: Hmm. It looks like I've been too long in C++ land. After a quick look around, I get the feeling that this trick doesn't work at all in C or Objective-C, since you can't statically initialise anything that requires code to be executed. So all I can offer is to either change the extension, as I suggested (which means convert to C++), or go with another answer. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Write two class methods to get the color and string for the text:

```
static NSArray *textColorList = nil;
static NSArray *stringList = nil;

// Creates the color list the first time this method is invoked. Returns one color object from the list.
+ (UIColor *)textColorWithIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    if (textColorList == nil) {
        textColorList = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIColor grayColor], .., nil];
    }

    // Mod the index by the list length to ensure access remains in bounds.
    return [textColorList objectAtIndex:(index+1) % [textColorList count]];
}

+ (NSString *)stringWithIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    if (stringList == nil) {
        stringList = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"my text 1", ... , nil];
    }

    return [stringList objectAtIndex:(index+1) % [stringList count]];
}
```